# Access webpage and execute inner javascript function

Tags: javascript, http, batch-file, automation

I've searched for the past 2 days and can't get an answer for what I'm looking for, so I've decided (after some years lurking) to finally create an account and ask for some tips.

I was looking for a way to (programatically) access a webpage and execute a javascript function built in it. This function exports a CSV file.

Is there a way to do this? PHP, curl, batch? I've searched for hours and can't find an answer.

All this javascript function does is submiting a form with the variables "xxx" and "yyy" (at least, after reading the source, that was all there was to it).

Also, the webpage has a login for which I have the credentials, but i really wanted to know (for now) if there is a way to create some kind of code to do this on a schedule.

Thanks in advance for the help.

**TL;DR:**

- go to www.webpage.com/blabla/final.aspx
- `javascript:__function('xxx','yyy')`
- JS function submits a form with arguments "xxx" and "yyy" to server
- output is a csv file sent from the server (popup with "save as")

Comment: check [phanotm.js](http://phantomjs.org/)  also you can use the webkit as a module through node.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium with JavascriptExecutor. See [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) and [JavascriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html)